# How do I return the signed value of certain bits

Tags: return, bit-shift, unsigned, signed

I'm trying to have this function return the signed value of bits 6-9 by use of the 2's complement but I keep getting a return value of -15. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
int signedBits6through9(int v)
{
    v = (v & 0b1111000000)>>6; // return the signed value in bits 6 through 9
    if (v & 0b1000)
        v = ~v + 1;
    return v;
}
```

Comment: What language are you using here? Also, in your example, the signed value of `1111` is equal to `-1`, but you are attempting to return `1`. Is that what you really want?

Comment: I'm using C, I just figured it out though, thanks!

Comment: `0b1111000000` compiles in C???

Comment: yes! it sure does. to my knowledge it's the same as writing an int but just represented in binary

Comment: So you've got this piece of code written in **C**, and you are able to compile it successfully? Hmmm, I would be happy to know what compiler you have there...